# Fluid simulation wont bake with obstacle object and it shape

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have to main problems and that is |
1) the Fluid simulation doesn't work in obstacle 
2) and even I removed the obstacle it won't take its shape of circular

[image]

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6893ol6yyv6le0/Fluid_test_1_1.blend?dl=0